# How to open links in browser from the app?

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an android application. I am currently opening a new activity with WebView when the user click on a URL. I want to change it load the URL inside the the browser. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```